# Calling string.reverse with or without () gives different results

Tags: scala

Newbie question:

Why is there a difference when I call reverse on a string with or without `()`

```
scala> "abc".reverse
res0: String = cba

scala> "abc".reverse()
                    ^
       error: not enough arguments for method apply: (i: Int)Char in class StringOps.
       Unspecified value parameter i.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That parses differently from what you think: String has an extension method `reverse`, with no parameter list, so as you've found out:

```
"abc".reverse == "cba"
```

You can index into a string.

```
"cba"(1) == 'c'
"cba"(2) == 'b'
```

or, in other words,

```
("abc".reverse)(1) == 'c'
("abc".reverse)(2) == 'b'
```

You don't need those parentheses:

```
"abc".reverse(1) == 'c'
"abc".reverse(2) == 'b'
```

but you can't leave out the index

```
("abc".reverse)() //missing parameter i
"abc".reverse() //missing parameter i
```